# How to make .net application installer which checks is .net framework installed if not download framework

Tags: .net, installation

I need to check if net framework installed, if it not installed it should be downloaded from microsoft website.

I know in that case i should use:

- some external script/component/language which not based on .net framework to provide universal independent installation

OR

- Use installation script which check .net framework, download it and after that run .net installer.

Is any good practice/examples/implementations of that feature?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure about old Setup Project template but ClickOnce installer can do it without any code. Just open project properties to Publish tab and choose prerequisites pushing same name button and click publish to create installer package.

More about is [How to: Install Prerequisites with a ClickOnce Application](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&checkda=1&ct=1353570151&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn%24msdn%24msdn&wreply=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x%2528v=vs.80%2529.aspx&lc=1033&id=254354&mkt=en-US)

Answer (score 0):

check if net framework installed:
you can check the specify path exist or not in regedit to judge the .net install or not. For example: check .net3.0 is installed, the path is:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\OFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Setup

Install .net
you can use .net setup package's commandline to silent install. For example:dotnetfx.exe /q:a /c:"install /l /q"